# Setting 404 Error page for JSP

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception, tomcat7, web.xml

I am trying to set a custom error-page in JSP. I am getting an error and I cannot figure out why. I have researched plenty of posts and I cannot seem to find an answer. When I visit a page that should throw me a 404, it sends me to the native Tomcat error page and not my own and throws this error.

```
Apr 30, 2015 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.PageNotFound_jsp._jspService(PageNotFound_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 30, 2015 11:33:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve custom
SEVERE: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/PageNotFound.jsp]
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /PageNotFound.jsp at line 38

35:         </div>
36:         
37:         Message:
38:         <div><%=exception.getMessage() %></div>
39:         StackTrace:
40:         <div><%
41:         StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.PageNotFound_jsp._jspService(PageNotFound_jsp.java:104)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    ... 22 more
```

Here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

And my PageNotFound.jsp

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

<title>Sample Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<!--content-->
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="span6 error">
                <img src="img/error.png" alt="">
            </article>
            <article class="span6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <h5>Sorry!</h5>
                        <h6>page not found</h6>
                        <div class="row">
                            <article class="span4">
                                <p class="margBot1">The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</p>
                                <p class="margBot1">Please try using our search box below to look for information on the website</p>

                            </article>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>

        Message:
        <div><%=exception.getMessage() %></div>
        StackTrace:
        <div><%
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
        exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
        out.println(stringWriter);
        printWriter.close();
        stringWriter.close();
        %></div>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PageNotFound.jsp is being attempted to be rendered. See the last stacktrace.

However, there is an exception occurring while trying to render that page. The "exception" variable in this line is null:

```
<div><%=exception.getMessage() %></div>
```

I think whenever there is an Exception in the java layer then this will variable will not be a null. So it makes sense to have this in an error page.

However in case of 404 condition, there are no exceptions in the Java layer, so it will be null. So, I don't think this code and the block of code below it, belongs in page that's used for 404 conditions.